# combobox is populated with enum values it is supposed to switch to specific case ,giving error

Tags: c#

> Blockquote
>   here enum is defined ,

```
 enum emotion
        { verysad, sad, normal, happy, veryhappy }
        emotion em = emotion.verysad;
        emotion m = emotion.sad;
        emotion o = emotion.normal;
        emotion t = emotion.happy;
        emotion i = emotion.veryhappy;



private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a = comboBox1.Text;
```

> Blockquotein 
>   here comboBox1 is populated with enum values when user click the button it should copy comboBox.text in string a and then switch to specific enum values and perform desired solution but unable to do the same.

```
            switch (a)
            {
                case em:
                    { em++;
                    textBox5.Text = em.ToString();

                    }
                case m:
                    {
                        m++;
                        textBox5.Text = m.ToString();
                    }
                case o:
                    { o++;
                    textBox5.Text = o.ToString();
                    }
                case t:
                    {
                        t++;
                        textBox5.Text = t.ToString();
                    }
                case i:
                    {

                        textBox5.Text = i.ToString();
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Edit your question please

Comment: why do you have `emotion m = emotion.sad` ? why not just use the `emotion.sad` to begin with?

Comment: because when case m executes i am incrementing  m then putting it in textBox5. just to increment i am using.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Incrementing enum variables seems highly suspicious to me. Perhaps the variables `em`, `m`, etc. are meant to be `int` counters?

Comment: And please, keep the actual error message. You deleted it from the title, but do add it back to the question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment asked, not sure why you are doing it this way ...
but in any case ,you can use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get your enum.

```
var parsed_enum = (emotion)Enum.Parse(typeof(emotion), comboBox1.Text);

switch (parsed_enum) {
   // logic here
}
```

---

as per comment, you are missing your `break;` . Here's some fiddle I've got:

```
string txt; // used since I'm just mocking it, no real textbox in my code.
var parsed_enum = (emotion)Enum.Parse(typeof(emotion), s);

switch (parsed_enum) {  
    case emotion.verysad:  
            /*
             * m++ is rubbish? are you trying to cycle to the next emotion?
             * or is this some kind of counter?
             * In any case, since an enum is an int, you can just increment it whatever it is.
             * for example:

                var v = emotion.sad;

                v++;    // now v is emotion.normal.

             */
            // m++ 
            txt = em.ToString();

            break;  // You can have one without the curly brackets.

    case emotion.sad: { 
            txt = m.ToString();
            break; // or inside them
        }

    case emotion.normal:
        {
            txt = o.ToString();
            break;
        }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I just noticed.. there is an error here. You need to pass in a `Type` object to `Parse()`,

Comment: @metacubed true. You also need to parse it back into the enum, since (like the MSDN source I've linked to in the answer says) it returns an object ...

Comment: @Noctis Yes? You cast it appropriately - that part was correct.

Comment: @metacubed yep, without the `(emotion)Enum.Parse ...`, you'll get a: `A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type`. I wrote the first answer from the top of my head, linking to the page that shows you how to do it properly :). All fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The text from the combobox is a string. Assuming it's a string containing the integer value of the enum, you'll have to cast it to an `emotion` before using it in the switch statement...

```
   switch ((emotion) Convert.ToInt32(a))
   {
       // ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The combo box value is probably the string "sad", "normal", etc. You can do enum parsing like se:

```
string a = comboBox1.Text;
string parsed = (emotion)Enum.Parse(typeof(emotion), a);
switch(parsed)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: hmmm ... just what i've said ... :)

Comment: @Noctis nooo.. you posted 34 sec. before me! :)

Comment: NONE OF YOUR SOLUTION WORKING DEAR.